# How to get lookup values from multiple columns from the same list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I am using SharePoint On-Prem 2019 and have a list on Site A, with the columns "Equipment Name" and "Serial Number" that I need to be able to lookup on Site B for the Trouble Ticket form. I have third party software that allows me to do a cross site lookup on the Trouble Ticket form which pulls the "Equipment Name" info from Site A (in a drop down list), but I need it to also link to the "Serial Number" column so we know which piece of equipment is being worked on.

Would it be possible to make the two columns associated somehow? Or do a cascading cross site lookup? Any info would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Lookup column does not support cross-site collection query in SharePoint, it is by design.

Howerver, Lookup column supports cross-subsites under the same site collection. For more information, please see "**[How to Create a Lookup Column to another SharePoint Site?](https://blog.mydock365.com/how-to-create-a-lookup-column-to-another-sharepoint-site)**".

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'RenderListDataAsStream' endpoint for lookup columns in other web. you can follow the solution provided in

https://sympmarc.com/tag/renderlistdataasstream/